# loading and unloading uiviewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

i don't really know how to handle a special case.

i know how to handle with view controllers when i'm using tabbars, or navigation controllers or something like this.

but now i want to build a game. and... games often don't have navigationcontrollers or tabbars, also mine doesn't have something like this.

so in my first view, i have u button, pushing this, initiates a new viewcontroller and adds his view as a subview on top of the fist view controller. ending this viewcontroller , i remove the new viewcontroller from superview.

but the viewcontroller is still initiated and in my memory.

do you have any tips for handling view controllers the way i want?
diplay view controller 1 -> click -> display view controller 2, unload 1 -> click -> display view controller 1 , unload 2

don't know if i'm right with the way i want. thanks for any tips about handling view controllers "game like"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use:

`-[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]`

to accomplish this? A lot less to maintain and you don't have to worry about the mechanics of memory management either (other than implementing `init`, `dealloc`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidUnload`).

Comment: ok, i can use `dismissmodelviewcontroller` then. but the object is still there (and running). in my special case some music gets played and some timers are running and they are still working after dismissing. `viewDidUnload` or `dealloc` doesn't get called after `dismissmodelviewcontroller`

Comment: figured out my problem. thanks your answer is correct. i have problems with a NSTimer that is going on after deallocating the object. i will ask this in a several question. thanks